# Allow more tags per employment history entry on careers.stackoverflow.com

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

Currently you are limited to 5 tags per job/degree on the new careers site, just like SO questions.  But a job/degree is typically more wide-ranging than a single SO question.  I would like to be able to display more (7-10 would be better).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we now allow up to 10 tags on job and education sections.